# Property of absolute value

Tags: real-analysis, absolute-value

How to prove for $x\in\Bbb R$, $-|x|\leq x\leq |x|$?I could prove it for the cases $x=0$ and for $x>0$.

$$|x| =
\left\{
 \begin{array}{ll}
         0 & \mbox{if } x =0 \\
   x  & \mbox{if } x > 0 \\
  -x & \mbox{if } x < 0
 \end{array}
\right.$$

**Case 1:When $x=0$**

$-|x|=x=|x|$ hence the inequality holds

**Case 2:When $x>0$**

We know that for all $x\in\mathbb R$:

$$\begin{align}
&|x|≥x && (i)\\
\Rightarrow&-|x|≤-x && (ii)
\end{align}$$

and when $x>0$
this implies $-x<0$

so $$–x<0<x\qquad (iii)$$

From (i),(ii) and (iii) We get

$$-|x|\leq-x<0<x\leq|x|\implies -|x|≤x≤|x|$$
hence the inequality holds

but I am not able to prove for the case $x<0$.

Comment: I have no idea what you mean when you write "using the fact that |x|≥x -|x|≤-x and x>0 -x<0 hence –x<0<x -|x|≤-x<0<x≤|x|
-|x|≤x≤|x|". This is complete jibberish. Please reformat your question to make it clear what it is you are proving, what statement follows from what statement and which are known from before. As it stands now, your question is just a bunch of symbols with no meaning to anyone except you.

Comment: Also, please use mathjax to format your question. https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: what is your definition of $|x|$ ?

Comment: -5xum thankyou so much.This is my first question of StackExchange I didn't know how to use mathjax.I'll edit my question.

Comment: @SrishtiBatra I edited your question substantially, as the formatting still needed work (which is OK, you are still learning!). I suggest you review the changes I made so that you will, in future, be able to better format your questions - this should be useful to you, because better formatting attracts more views to your question, and more views mean that users are more likely to answer!

Comment: Try to use property here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_value#Real_numbers  $|x|={\begin{cases}x,&{\text{if }}x\geq 0\\-x,&{\text{if }}x<0.\end{cases}}$

Comment: @5xum thank you for helping me out and teaching me

Comment: For future reference: write entire mathematical expressions, not just individual symbols, in math mode. In other words, write `$f(x)=\frac{1}{x} + 10$` (which yields "$f(x)=\frac{1}{x} + 10$") instead of `f(x)=$\frac{1}{x}$ + 10` which yields a much uglier "f(x)=$\frac{1}{x}$ + 10"

Comment: @5xum thankyou so much. Will keep that in mind.

Comment: You recieved 2 answers to your question. Is any of them what you needed? If so, consider *accepting* the best answer and upvoting all useful answers you got. That's how the site works.

Comment: @5xum I tried  but it says I need atleast 15 reputations to vote

Comment: @Faith You do not need 15 reputation to accept the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are **way** overcomplicating the case when $x>0$. Remember, from the definition of absolute values, what is the absolute value of a positive number?

**Hint**: Take a look at some examples of positive numbers. What are $|1|, |2|, |1000|, |\pi|, |e|$?

---

For the negative numbers, the task should be even simpler. Remember that one of the fundamental properties of the absolute value is that it is always **non-negative**. So, from that, if $x<0$, can you see why $x<|x|$ (remember, again, $|x|$ is **non-negative!**)

Comment: Thank you ,I got this part. Please can you also teach me the how to write the proof for the part -|x|<=x

Comment: @SrishtiBatra Go case by case again

Comment: @SrishtiBatra Also, please keep in mind my first sentence. You are overcomplicating. If $x>0$, then $|x|=x$ by definition, so $x\leq |x|$ clearly holds. Also, if $x>0$, then $-|x|<0$, so clearly, from $-|x|<0$ and $0<x$, you have $-|x|<x$.  You can do the other cases just as easily.

Comment: that's great,now I understand.Thank you so much for bearing with me and being patient with me

Answer (score 0):

By definition of absolute value we can write,

$$\begin{align}&x≥0\\
\iff &-x≤0≤x\\
\iff &|x|=x≥x≥-x \end{align}$$

and

$$\begin{align}&x<0\\
\iff&-x>0>x\\
\iff& |x|=-x≥-x>x \end{align} $$

This immediately implies,

$$|x|≥x ~~\text{and}~~ |x|≥-x$$

This means,

$$-|x|≤x≤|x|.$$